# Efficient/Fastest way to compute minimal distance between groups in a data frame

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization, distance

I have a data frame looks like:

```
x y group
1 2  1 
1 3  1
1 4  2
1 5  2
1 6  3
...
```

For each group, I would like to find the distance to its 'nearest' group. Here, nearest is defined as the group which has the shortest distance to that group; and distance is defined as the shortest distance between all members from those two groups. For example, the distances between all members within group 1 to all members within group 2 is:

```
(1,2) -> (1,4) = 2
(1,2) -> (1,5) = 3
(1,3) -> (1,4) = 1
(1,3) -> (1,5) = 2
```

1 is the shortest, therefore the distance between group 1 and 2 is 1.
Same idea, the distances between all members within group 1 to all members within group  is:

```
(1,2) -> (1,6) = 4
(1,3) -> (1,6) = 3
```

therefore the distance between group 1 and 3 is 3. Since 3 > 1, therefore the nearest neighbor to group 1 is group 2, and the distance is 1.
I would like to apply this metric to a really large dataset and I am able to achieve this idea using nested-for loops, but apparently it is very slow. Is there any faster solution? Appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach that loops over pairs of groups but is at least vectorized within pairs:

```r
d <- data.frame(x = 1L, y = 2:6, group = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L))
m <- do.call(rbind, d[c("x", "y")])
l <- lapply(split(seq_len(ncol(m)), d$group), function(j) m[, j, drop = FALSE])
rm(m); gc()

distance <- function(x, y) {
    j <- rep(seq_len(ncol(x)), each = ncol(y))
    min(sqrt(colSums((x[, j, drop = FALSE] - as.vector(y))^2)))
}

D <- outer(l, l, Vectorize(distance))
D
##   1 2 3
## 1 0 1 3
## 2 1 0 1
## 3 3 1 0
```

I would avoid `outer`, though, since it doesn't take advantage of the properties of the distance function, namely that `distance(x, x) == 0` and `distance(x, y) == distance(y, x)` for all groups `x` and `y`. To obtain the `outer` result more efficiently, I would do:

```r
D <- matrix(0, length(l), length(l))
D[lower.tri(D)] <- combn(length(l), 2L, function(i) distance(l[[i[1L]]], l[[i[2L]]]))
D <- D + t(D)
D
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    0    1    3
## [2,]    1    0    1
## [3,]    3    1    0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the distance between each pair of `x`, `y` points using `stats::dist()`. After a little manipulation of the results using {broom} and {dplyr}, you can find the minimum distance within each pair of `groups`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

df <- data.frame(
  x = rep(1, 5),
  y = 2:6,
  group = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3)
)

item_groups <- df %>% 
  transmute(item = factor(row_number()), group)

dist(df[c("x", "y")]) %>% 
  broom::tidy() %>% 
  left_join(item_groups, by = c("item1" = "item")) %>% 
  left_join(item_groups, by = c("item2" = "item"), suffix = c(".1", ".2")) %>% 
  group_by(group.1, group.2) %>% 
  filter(group.1 != group.2, distance == min(distance))

#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#> # Groups:   group.1, group.2 [3]
#>   item1 item2 distance group.1 group.2
#>   <fct> <fct>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 2     3            1       1       2
#> 2 2     5            3       1       3
#> 3 4     5            1       2       3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- tribble(
      ~x, ~y, ~group,
      1,2, 1,
      1,3, 1,
      1,4, 2,
      1,5, 2,
      1,6, 3
    )
    data %>% 
      mutate(sum_of_x_y = x+y) %>% 
      group_by(group)%>% 
      summarize(min_group =  min(sum_of_x_y))

# group min_group
# <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 3           
# 2 5           
# 3 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way

```
g = length(unique(df$grp))

matrix(
  df[, `:=`(con = 1)][df,allow.cartesian=T,on="con"] %>% 
  .[,dist:=sqrt((x-i.x)^2 + (y-i.y)^2)] %>% 
  .[, min(dist), by=.(grp,i.grp)] %>% 
  .[order(grp, i.grp),V1],g,g)
```

Output:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    1    3
[2,]    1    0    1
[3,]    3    1    0
```

If you have too many points to do the full cartesian join, you can do this, where you do for each of the pairs:

```
df[,con:=1]

func <- function(df) {
  df[df,allow.cartesian=T,on="con"] %>% 
    .[,dist:=sqrt((x-i.x)^2 + (y-i.y)^2)] %>% 
    .[grp!=i.grp, min(dist), by=.(grp,i.grp)][1,V1]
}

grps = unique(df$grp)
vals = apply(combn(grps,2), 2, \(p) func(df[grp %in% p]))
M = matrix(0, length(grps),length(grps))
M[lower.tri(M)] <- vals
M[upper.tri(M)] <- vals

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    1    3
[2,]    1    0    1
[3,]    3    1    0
```